# Ошибка 'pom.xml' has syntax errors в pom.xml файле

Tags: java, junit, jenkins

Пытаюсь установить jUnit 5 для автотестов на Jenkins для своего проекта. Для этого в файл pom.xml Добавляю следующий код:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                <dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST_VERSION</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>2.4.1</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Все плагины с ошибками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться плиз и исправить ошибки. Очень похоже на ошибки версий.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Закройте тэг <dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тег  закрыл. Но проблема осталась. Пришлось для каждого плагина ручками найти последнюю версию и тогда проблема решилась. Всем спасибо.

Comment: В таком случае предлагаю отметить данный ответ как верный (галочка слева) и закрыть данный вопрос, заранее спасибо :)